# Why change of sequence in cmd command gives different result?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm new in using cmd and batch script. Here is what I was trying to do with a **.bat** file.

1. go to a folder
2. open that folder in file explorer
3. open that folder in vscode
4. start Firefox browser

**Sequence doesn't matter here. Doing these tasks in any sequence is fine.**

Here are the commands that I initially wrote

```
cd/
E:
cd folder1/folder2/folder3
code .
start .
start firefox
```

But with these commands the result I got is

1. Only vscode started with the folder I wanted to open with vscode
2. File explorer and Firefox was not starting
3. cmd.exe continued to run. But it seems like it only executed upto **code .** command
4. When I closed vscode, cmd.exe would be closed with it too

Then I changed the sequence of the commands as below

```
cd/
E:
cd folder1/folder2/folder3
start .
start firefox
code .
```

This time everything worked as expected. I've looked up documentation for **start** command but didn't find anything(or maybe I didn't understand) about **start .** command. 
Can anyone explain me why the result changed when I changed the sequence of the commands?

Comment: The default behaviour of START is to instantiate a new process that runs in parallel with the main process. If you do not use the `START` command, the parser waits for the current command that is executing to end or exit it's processing before the next command is executed.

Comment: Is `code` a batch file on its own? if so, use `call code .`…

Comment: no "code ." is the command that I used to start vscode

Comment: So it is an executable, I guess; what's the output of `where code` in a Command Prompt window?

Comment: After `code .` has been executed vscode starts and cmd is in the directory that I specified. I hope that's what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [already mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71029265/why-change-of-sequence-in-cmd-command-gives-different-result#comment125565176_71029265), `code` is really a batch file, `code.cmd`.

*If your VSCode installer added a location to your `%PATH%`, take a look there and you should see `code.cmd` in that `\bin` directory.*

When you run a batch file from another, if you want control to pass back to the initial script upon completion, you need to run it using the `call` command.

```sh
@CD /D "E:\folder1\folder2\folder3" 2>NUL || Exit /B
@Call "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" .
@Start "" "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe" .
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

If you do not want robust code, and wish to assume file extensions and environment settings, the above could be simplified to this:

```sh
@CD /D E:\folder1\folder2\folder3
@Call code .
@Start explorer .
@Start firefox
```